# Fix a pie-chart plot to make it more readable by adding a Legend

Tags: ggplot2, pivot, legend, pie-chart, geom-bar

I need to fix the following pie chart, I need a legend with the names of the countries (percentages can be fine like this.

```
COMP_plot <- comp_plot %>%
      select(-commodity) %>% 
      pivot_longer(cols = names(.)) %>% 
      mutate(name = factor(name, levels = rev(name))) %>%
      mutate(position = cumsum(lag(value, default = 0)) + value/2) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = value, y = 1, fill = name)) + 
      geom_col() + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity",color = "black") +
      geom_text(aes(x = position, y = 2.3, label = name)) +
      geom_text(aes(x = position, y = 1.7, label = value), colour = "black") +
      coord_polar() + 
      theme_void() +
      guides(fill = "none") +
      labs(title = "Cotton Exports by country of origin") 
    COMP_plot
```

this is the data frame I used:

```
> comp_plot
# A tibble: 1 x 7
  commodity China Australia India Rep.of.Korea Thailand   ROW
  <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 Cotton     14.1       2.1   6.2          2.2      1.1  74.3
```

[image]

Comment: Just comment out this line     `geom_text(aes(x = position, y = 2.3, label = name)) +` and this line `guides(fill = "none") +`

Comment: perfect thanks! what if i also wanted "%" next to numbers?

Comment: change `geom_text(aes(x = position, y = 1.7, label = value)` to `geom_text(aes(x = position, y = 1.7, label = paste(value,"%"))`